# WCF Service - What happens if a wcf client/channel isn't explicitly closed?

Tags: .net, wcf, garbage-collection, wcf-client

Say we have the following class in client app:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public void CallWCFService()
    {
        WCFClient svcClient = new WCFClient("endpointName");

        var x = svcClient.GetFoo();

        // no Close() or Abort() method here...    
    }
}
```

What happens if I create an instance of `TestClass` from a different class, and call it's `CallWCFService()` method?

Does garbage collection take care of the svcClient?

Does this mean that the service host have an unavailable channel until svcClient eventually dies somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes until the session (if you have one) reaches the timeout you will have a pending connection, depending of how your service is configured that usually drives to great problems

Comment: Is that a yes to garbage collection closing the channel or a yes to the service having an unavailable channel until a client channel dies?

Comment: Is yes for both of them, if you have a session the garbage collector will take care of the proxy but just when the session times out, so you have one connection alive and unavailable on the service